# Is custom static allocator possible? / A way to fake it?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

**Background:**
For hardware dependant reasons, I need to allocate memory of using the [DOS Protected Mode Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS_Protected_Mode_Interface) in order to communicate with some low-level interfaces (e.g. [VESA BIOS Extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA_BIOS_Extensions)).

**Situation:**
So I can overload `new` and `delete` for dynamically allocated memory which is great but I really want to overload the allocators for statically allocated memory.  The project I'm working on is rather old library and therefore requires a fair number of static global variables.

**Question:**
Is there some way I could overload the allocation process for these variables?  If not, is there a template to dynamically allocate these variables that wouldn't require explicit allocation or deletion and be almost entirely transparent?

Comment: Global variables, static or not, are not allocated dynamically on the heap. They are put in special segments that are initialized when the program is loaded. The storage in the special segments is done by the compiler, the initialization of the segments in memory is done by the program loader before your program is running.

Comment: Are you targeting MS DOS? Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Yes, I'm targetting MS-DOS using DJGPP (i586-pc-msdosdjgpp-gcc (GCC) 6.3.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, there is no keyword to specify the type of memory allocation you wish to use and there are no standard templates to force heap allocation.  The best answer I could find was to just make a small wrapper class a that allocates and deletes memory how you want and provides you with access to the pointer.  It's nothing fancy but here's some of my code.

```
template<typename T>
class mem
{
public:
  mem(void) { m_data = reinterpret_cast<T*>(dos::malloc(sizeof(T))); }
 ~mem(void) { dos::free(m_data); m_data = nullptr; }
  T* operator ->(void) noexcept { return m_data; }
  operator T*(void) noexcept { return m_data; }

private:
  T* m_data;
};
```